# как избежать цикла в цикле

Tags: javascript, циклы, оптимизация

Задача на codewars: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5547cc7dcad755e480000004

```js
function removeNb(n) {
  let arr = new Array(n)
  let result = []
  while (n > 0) {
    arr[n - 1] = n
    n--
  }

  for (let flag = 1; flag < arr.length; flag++) {
    arr.splice(flag - 1, 1)
    arr.forEach((cursor) => {
      let temp = arr.slice(cursor, arr.length)
      let difference = arr.filter((x) => !temp.includes(x))

      difference.splice(difference.indexOf(cursor), 1)
      temp = difference.concat(temp)
      temp = temp.reduce((sum, el) => (sum += el))
      if (flag * cursor === temp) {
        result.push([flag, cursor])
      }
    })
    arr.splice(flag - 1, 0, flag)
  }
  return result
}

let result = removeNb(26)
console.log(result)
```

```css
code {white-space: nowrap !important;}
```

Решение написал, но из-за цикла в цикле на больших числах превышаю лимит по времени выполнения, как можно оптимизировать данную функцию? Как избежать цикла в цикле? Где-то что-то читал про n log n, однако, ничего не понял и стало очень интересно, как это реализовать. Если кто-то возьмется растолковать что к чему - буду безмерно благодарен за развернутый ответ с пояснениями. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: вы бы и условие задачи сюда перенесли бы, а то лениво бывает от ссылки к ссылке сказать

Comment: Применить немного математики. Пусть сумма `1+..+n = S`. Тогда условие на выбранные числа записывается как `S - a - b = a * b`. Нехитрыми преобразованиями получаем выражение `b = (S - a)/(a + 1)`. Итого можно бежать в цикле по `a`, вычислять `b` и проверять что оно целое и лежит в нужном диапазоне значений.

Comment: Ну и да, массив для этого совершенно не нужен

Comment: @AlexeyTen, оформите как ответ. я галочку поставлю. Спасибо большое. Вопрос можно закрыть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Применить немного математики.

Обозначим сумму `S = 1 + ... + n = n * (n + 1) / 2`. Тогда условие на выбранные числа записывается как `S - a - b = a * b`. Нехитрыми преобразованиями получаем выражение `b = (S - a)/(a + 1)`.

Итого можно бежать в цикле по `a`, вычислять `b` и проверять что оно целое и лежит в нужном диапазоне значений.